# Why should we stop using Laravel Blade and adapt Angular Js or Node Js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.37 for CRUD. Blade are also implemented inside same code. I meant, database interaction and UI both are part of same project.

## Question:

Somebody suggested me to use Angular Js for UI and backend for Laravel. Laravel should respond with JSON data only.

I never worked on Angular Js or Node Js. I have no idea if I should change the complete code before I keep developing the things as project is large so its better to decide at design kind of stage only.

Can you kindly suggest if I should continue with Laravel Blade?

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS is a server-side technology, which means that it is used in place of Laravel, and thus would require to rewrite the whole project in NodeJS.

---

Considering AngularJS, it's up to you to choose the technology that suits you, but it would require to rewrite all the frontend part of your application. If you don't **need** AngularJS, then I see no reason to switch to it.

You should look for examples on the [official AngularJS website](https://angularjs.org/) and decide if it's a better option than Laravel Blade.

That said, if you're fine using Blade, and AngularJS is not bringing you any interesting feature, just stick to it.

The AngularJS thing is just a trend, and people assume that if you want to be cool you have to use it.

Comment: I already have my Controller, Model, View implemented in Laravel. Now, I have a requirement for an Android App. In my existing code, I have many places where I am returning JSON data. That's the reason I thought to keep the Laravel code for Service and use angular js for website front end. In this way service will become common for both platforms. Is it good approach to have API controller separate in same application if I have to ignore angular js?

Comment: In this case you could indeed benefit from having a single controller for both frontend and API that would return JSON then consumed by either your android application or a frontend application (be it in AngularJS or any other technology). That said, what you could do would be to indentify in your unique controller if the request comes from a mobile or if it comes from a browser, and either return the view or return the JSON based on that, which would allow you to have a unique controller, but still use Blade.

Answer (score -1):

Stop using Laravel Blade, instead use Angular 2 or Angular Js 1, call your php method from angular and use angular to render data on your ui. Laravel send JSON data in response.

Comment: Why should we stop to use Laravel blade?

Answer (score -3):

The combination of angular js with nodejs is good. You can try using mean stack which generate complete scaffolding code with angular js in ui side and node js on server side

Comment: Should I use Laravel anywhere in the code? For the API point of view?

Comment: Laravel is based on php so i would suggest not to use it. There is a learning curve. There are good support for angular with nodejs. you will find lot of seed project using angularjs and node js in git hub.